# Can't open my photoshop document directly

Tags: adobe, photoshop

I am using Photoshop CS6 and I am facing a problem in that.

when I open Photoshop application it opens in 64 bits but when I open the PSD file it cant open in the document directly.

I have to first open Photoshop and then the PSD file and it's very boring sometime to open first Photoshop and then my psd file.

Why can't I open my psd file directly? Please help.

Thank you.

Comment: what error are you getting?   
Right click on PSD doc=>open with=>choose Adobe Photoshop=>select check box *Use this program to open all files of this type*

Comment: Oh got it. Such a sily mistake. Sorry and thanks.! @Bit_hunter

Comment: Not a programming question....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Steps:-**
**1** Right click on PSD doc
**2** open with=>choose Adobe Photoshop
**3** select check box Use this program to open all files of this type